# Error in WPF when trying to read and write from a file using C#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, visual-studio-2010

So I am trying to read and write from/in .xml file and I get this error:

```
'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' does not contain a definition for 'load' and no extension method 'load' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

for line:

```
document.load("MyXmlFile.xml");
```

Code Sample:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;      // I included this for XDocument
using System.Xml.XPath;     // I included this because I thought it will fix a problem

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();

    public void LoadXML()
    {
        var document = new XDocument();

        if (!File.Exists("MyXmlFile.xml"))
             document.Save("MyXmlFile.xml");
        else document.load("MyXmlFile.xml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your method a little:

```
if (!File.Exists("MyXmlFile.xml"))
{
    document.Save("MyXmlFile.xml");
}
else
{
    //We know it exists so we can load it
    document = XDocument.Load("MyXmlFile.xml"); // changed
}

//Continue to work with document
```

Comment: Changed it to Load and i got  a new error:


Member 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: When i try to run it for the second time, i get a waning saying :
root element is missing.
Any tips?

Comment: @C-PROG, It is because your document is empty and doesn't contain any Element, if you add some element (i.e. <elem> </elem>) everything will work fine